# Flask - Submit button submits all forms instead of one form

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm using two forms in one of my pages one for closing tickets and one for sending replies.
But problem is when I submit one of them another one is submitted too! and shows the flash massages. So I have two flash massages !
That gets more complicated since I'm checking some conditions to show first form and in that case which that form even doesn't again I have two flash massages !

```
@app.route('/edit-ticket', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_ticket():
if session['logged_in'] == True:
    trackingNumberLink = int(request.args.get('trackingNumber'))
    closeForm = CloseTicket()
    editForm = EditTicket()
    GetTicketStatus = tickets.find_one({"trackingNumber": trackingNumberLink})
    if closeForm.validate_on_submit():
        tickets.update_one({"trackingNumber": trackingNumberLink},
                           {"$set": {"status": "پاسخ داده شده", "order": 2}})
        flash(u"تیکت مورد نظر با موفقیت بسته شد.")
    if editForm.validate_on_submit():
        replyDate = jdatetime.datetime.now()
        tickets.update_one({"trackingNumber": trackingNumberLink},
                           {"$set": {"status": "در حال بررسی", "order": 1}})
        tickets.update_one({"trackingNumber": trackingNumberLink},
                           {"$push": {"replies": {"rep": {"mass": editForm.ticketMassage.data,
                                                          "date": replyDate.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%y "),
                                                          "HowSent": "user"}}}})
        flash(u"پاسخ با موفقیت ارسال شد.")
    return render_template('edit-ticket.html', Title="ویرایش تیکت", closeForm=closeForm,
                           editForm=editForm, CanUserCloseTicket=GetTicketStatus)
else:
    return redirect(url_for('Login'))
```

HTML:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content_main %}
<div class="container content-box">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="FormSection center-form">
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">ویرایش تیکت</legend>
                </fieldset>
                <form method="post" action="">
                    {{ editForm.hidden_tag() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ editForm.ticketMassage.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                        {% if editForm.ticketMassage.errors %}
                            {{ editForm.ticketMassage(class="form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in editForm.ticketMassage.errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ editForm.ticketMassage(class="form-control-lg") }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ editForm.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            {% if CanUserCloseTicket['status'] != "پاسخ داده شده" %}
                <div class="FormSection center-form">
                    <form method="post" action="">
                        {{ closeForm.hidden_tag() }}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ closeForm.submitCloseTicket(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock content_main %}
```

Forms Class:

```
class EditTicket(FlaskForm):
    ticketMassage = TextAreaField('متن پیام:',
                              description=u'پاسخ خود را بنویسید.',
                              validators=[data_required(), Length(min=20, max=500)], )
    submit = SubmitField('ویرایش تیکت')


class CloseTicket(FlaskForm):
    submitCloseTicket = SubmitField('بستن تیکت')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render the form tag with an id attribute and for the submit and input tags use the form attribute.

```
<form id="edit-ticket">
    {{ form.submit(form="edit-ticket") }}
```

> The form element that the input element is associated with (its form owner). The value of the attribute must be an id of a  element in the same document. If this attribute isn't used, the  element is associated with its nearest ancestor  element, if any. This attribute lets you to place  elements anywhere within a document, not just as descendants of form elements.

**Update** Use different names for `submit` then in your `views.py` `if close_form.validate_on_submit() and close_form.close.data:`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm, CSRFProtect
from wtforms.fields import SubmitField, TextAreaField

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '^%huYtFd90;90jjj'
app.config['UPLOADED_FILES'] = 'static/files'


csrf = CSRFProtect(app)


class EditTicketForm(FlaskForm):
    ticket_message = TextAreaField()
    edit = SubmitField()


class CloseTicketForm(FlaskForm):
    message = TextAreaField()
    close = SubmitField()


@app.route('/edit-ticket', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_ticket():
    close_form = CloseTicketForm()
    edit_form = EditTicketForm()
    if close_form.is_submitted() and close_form.close.data:
        if close_form.validate():
            x = close_form.message.data
            return x.upper()
    if edit_form.is_submitted() and edit_form.edit.data:
        if edit_form.validate():
            y = edit_form.ticket_message.data
            return y.upper()
    return render_template('edit-ticket.html', close_form=close_form, edit_form=edit_form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

edit-ticket.html

```
<form method="post" id="edit-form" novalidate></form>
<form method="post" id="close-form" novalidate></form>
    {{ edit_form.csrf_token(form="edit-form") }}
    {{ close_form.csrf_token(form="close-form") }}
    {{ edit_form.ticket_message(form="edit-form") }}
    {{ edit_form.edit(form="edit-form") }}
    {{ close_form.message(form="close-form") }}
    {{ close_form.close(form="close-form") }}
```

Comment: Hi Roy and thanks for reply. I had tried your advice and added id two both forms and submit bottoms but still I have the same problem.

Comment: The form elements should also have the `form=""` attribute`

Comment: I did what you said but still no luck. See, when I'm submitting one form it goes on other form validate_on_submit() condition too and that's why I have two flash massages by the fact that in some case I don't have two forms in page !

Comment: I've updated the answer, `if close_form.validate_on_submit() and close_form.close.data:` solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for update. Problem solved. but I still have little conflict which is: when I have two forms ready in my page and I click on close ticket it checks edit ticket form and give me validation error for that ! screenshot: http://uupload.ir/files/xmh3_capture.png

Comment: Thats not a `Flask-WTF` error add `novalidate` to your form tag. `<form method="post" id="edit-form" novalidate></form>`

Comment: I've separated `is_submitted()` and `validate()` from `validate_on_submit()`.

Comment: Its exactly for Flask-WTF. Let me tell you how I'm sure. Because I had changed validation massage in my form class and I saw that massage !

Comment: You're right, separate `validate_on_submit()` and it'll work fine. I've checked.

Comment: Roy Thanks for your help and time body. I hope u have good days ahead

Answer (score 0):

Put an action on your forms instead of leaving it blank:

```
<form method="post" action="/close-ticket"> ... </form>

<form method="post" action="/edit-ticket"> ... </form>
```

Define explicit functions to handle each action.  One action, one function - keep it simple.  Split out and re-use the logged-in logic for each.

```
@app.route('/close-ticket', methods=['POST'])
def close_ticket():
    if session['logged_in'] != True:
        return redirect(url_for('Login'))
    # closeForm handling, etc....

@app.route('/edit-ticket', methods=['POST'])
def edit_ticket():
    if session['logged_in'] != True:
        return redirect(url_for('Login'))
    # editForm handling, etc....
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I appreciate your help but I need both form in one page and one rout. This example you had wrote is working just fine but its not my case.